# How to convert uint32_t to struct in_addr?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
uint32_t ip = 0;
printf("%s\n",inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)ip));
return 0;
}
```

I don't want to do this by declaring any temporary variable. This program gives segmentation fault.

```
struct in_addr {
    uint32_t s_addr; 
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're casting an int to a pointer.  Perhaps you want this:

```
*(struct in_addr *)&ip
```

But the result is implementation-defined (for a start, there're endianness considerations).

Comment: How can I do htonl in the same line?

Comment: The result is implementation UNdefined. It gives an warning: error: dereferencing pointer 'ip' does break strict-aliasing rules